# Cucumber JVM - get reference to all scenarios

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

is there possibility to get reference to ALL scenarios in Cucumber JVM?

Problem: I need to pragmatically count some statistics about scenarios (failed, total count, etc)

For failed, I could create @After hook, and bump variable that holds number of failed scenarios:

```
@After(order = 1)
public void onScenarioFinished(Scenario scenario)
{
    if (scenario.isFailed())
    {
        failedScenarios++;
    }
}
```

But is there possibility to access all 'Scenario' objects that cucumber loaded?

Comment: U can use getStatus() which returns an enum Result which contains all the options. -- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/Result.java... Or u can create a custom plugin extending EventListener allowing callback methods which u can use. There is also an existing plugin that gets statistics - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/formatter/Stats.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating ***@Before*** hook, that adds scenario reference to the list.

This way I have reference to all scenarios that were started.

```
List<Scenario> scenarios = new ArrayList();

@Before(order = 0)
public void onScenarioStarted(Scenario scenario)
{
    scenarios.add(Scenario);
}
```